# Is an intersection of algebraically closed subfields algebraically closed?

Tags: solution-verification, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and $\lbrace A_i\rbrace_{i\in I}$ be a collection of algebraically closed subfields of $K$. Here is my attempted proof that $A:=\cap_{i\in I}A_i$ is an algebraically closed subfield of $K$, but something doesn't seem right about it.

An intersection of subfields is a subfield, so $A$ is a subfield. Let $p$ be a non-zero polynomial over $A$ and $\lambda$ be root of $p$ in $K$. For each $i\in I$, we have that $p$ is a non-zero polynomial over $A_i$, $A_i$ is algebraically closed and $\lambda$ is a root of $p$, so $\lambda\in A_i$. This is true for each $i\in I$, so $\lambda\in A$.

It follows that for each non-zero polynomial over $A$, its roots are contained in $A$, hence $A$ is algebraically closed.

But I'm not too confident about this. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. In general, properties related to ”closeness” behave well with intersections (as you mentioned, the intersection of fields is a field, etc) and the argument for that is the one you posted.